# Spring Rest Paging not displaying correct results

Tags: rest, spring-data

Can someone help me with Pagination, here is my controller method code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search")
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<OrderResource>> search(
        @Valid OrderSearch search,
        @PageableDefault(size=5) @SortDefault(sort = "poNumber", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Order> orders = orderService.search(search, pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<OrderResource>>(
            pagedAssembler.toResource(orders, orderAssembler),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I got about 22 records in the table and here is the page properties it displays when I hit the controller first time

```
{
  "metadata": {
     "**size" : 10, 
     "totalElements" : 22,
     "totalPages" : 3,
     "number" : 0},
  "nextLink" : {
     "rel" : "next", 
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/restapp/orders/search?poNumber=1000&page=1&size=10", 
     "variableNames" : [], 
     "variables" : [], 
     "templated" : false },
  "previousLink" : null,
  "id" : null
}
```

Any reason why there is `page=1` in the next link and when I hit below the records are not refreshing

Here is my servlet config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
                <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <!-- Handle XML input -->
                <ref bean="jaxbHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id= "conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

   <bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.HateoasSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />

   <bean  class="org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
               <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <null />
        </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" /> 

    <!-- Configure the XML JAXB marshaller  -->
    <bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.emc.it.eis.channeltracker.model" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Message converter for XML requests and responses -->
    <bean id="jaxbHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    </bean>
```

http://localhost:8080/restapp/orders/search?poNumber=1000&page=2&size=10

Answer (score 0):

`Page`s are zero indexed by default, just as `List`s are in Java. 0 demarcates the first page, 1 the second and so on.

This can be tweaked by piping a custom `HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to the `PagedResourcesAssembler` that you use. On the former, configured `setOneIndexedParameters(…)`to `true`.

This will cause the HTTP interaction (i.e. the request parameters) work with one-indexed pages: i.e. `?page=1` will request the first page and the link will then point to `?page=2` for the second page. Note, that internally the `Pageable`and `Page` instances will still use zero-indexing as they're plain value objects and behave accordingly.

Comment: Oliver, i have added my current servlet config ,I think i have the same config what you suggested, but please check and let me know if there is anything needs to be added, Also could you please tell me when i go to page2 link why i don't see updated results, i should technically see the next stack, also if you look at i have @PageableDefault(size=5) but still when i hit the the url first time i see 10 results